# How to save out the contents of a single cell to a single text file

Tags: excel, vba, text, export

I have a series of cells that I would like to automatically save into individual text files at set intervals. Ideally, this would happen on a timer, say once a minute while the macro is running.

I have 4 headings with 15 entries each, for a total of 60 cells of content. I would essentially like those 60 cells to update 60 text files with their content.

ie:

cell `A1` gets save out as `P1username.txt . . . . contents of file: Bill`

cell `A2` gets save out as `P2username.txt . . . . contents of file: Bob`

cell `A3` gets save out as `P3username.txt . . . . contents of file: Tom`

cell `A`4 gets save out as: `P4username.txt . . . . contents of file: Joe`

cell `B1` gets save out as `P1address.txt . . . . contents of file: 123 Street`

cell `B2` gets save out as `P2address.txt . . . . contents of file: 456 Avenue`

cell `B3` gets save out as `P3address.txt . . . . contents of file: 789 Way`

cell `B4` gets save out as `P4address.txt . . . . contents of file: 1000 Road`

and so on.

Is this possible?

--

The overall purpose is to populate the contents of a particular stream HUD in Streamlabs OBS. I currently manually trigger a macro which exports the data from excel, into a comma delimited text file, then into Photoshop and using dataset tools generates one large image that gets used in the GUI. However, this is time consuming (I have the macro down to 30 seconds, during which time I cannot otherwise use the PC) and I would like to streamline it, and automate it so that it can run in the background without me triggering it, or tying up the PC. I hoped that with it on a timer I could simply turn it on at the start of the stream and off again at the end. However, manually running it as needed is also acceptable.

I work in VBA maybe once every 5 years so I essentially learn it again when I need it. I want to make sure I'm on the right track. I'm hoping someone has a few ideas on the best way to accomplish this.

--

So far I have this working. I can probably run similar code for all 60 entries and then figure out a way to trigger it to run when a cell value changes. Is there a more elegant/better way?

```
Sub run()

Dim myFile As String

myFile = "C:\username\HUD\P1username.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Print #1, Range("C4")
Close #1

myFile = "C:\username\HUD\P1address.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #2
Print #2, Range("C5")
Close #2

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I've added what I have so far. Thanks Miles

Answer (score 1):

I have it working. When any cell within the range is changed, the macro runs automatically. The macro dumps the contents of the 60 cells into 60 text files. For anyone else this may help, here is what I did:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will run the macro when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("C4:L19")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

' Put the macro you want to run here:

Dim myFile As String

myFile = "C:\username\HUD\P1username.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Print #1, Range("C4")
Close #1

myFile = "C:\username\HUD\P1address.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Print #1, Range("C5")
Close #1

' Repeat this as many times as you want. I have 60 cycles.

End If
End Sub
```

Cheers

Comment: One little improvement: Specify in which sheet your `Range` objects are. By using `Me.Range` it will specify the same sheet where `Target` is in. Do this for all 4 `Range()` objects.